# Suddenly pdf export code does not work any more. Is there something wrong with my code?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code for exporting to pdf to a speciffic folder on Sharepoint. The code always worked fine until resently. And I can't figure out why. In the code I have 2 strings for path, that I combine. If I cut out part of the path it works.

So it makes me think there is a problem with the path. I check plenty times that the path is correct and cant see that it has changed. 
I get the

> Run-time error 1004: application-defined of object-defined error

If I change `Filename:=newpath3` 
to
`Filename:=newpath1`
It exports the pdf. So is there something wrong with newpath2? I checked with msgbox and cant find any mistake with the total path.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() 
    Dim newpath1 As String
    Dim newpath2 As String
    Dim newpath3 As String

    newpath1 = Left(ActiveWorkbook.Path, 66)
    newpath2 = "99%20Vedlegg%20til%20faktura"
    newpath3 = newpath1 & newpath2

    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=newpath3 & "/" & "test", _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: hi, can u post the values of newpath1, newpath2, and newpath3 ? thanks

Comment: Please check if `ActiveWorkbook` is really what you want. This is the workbook that has the focus / is on top at the moment this code runs. This can be any worbkoo the user clicks on. If you meant to use the workbook where the code is running in then you must use `ThisWorkbook` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Individual components of a filename (i.e. each subdirectory along the path, and the final filename) are limited to 255 characters, and the total path length is limited to approximately 32,000 characters.

However, on Windows, you can't exceed MAX_PATH value (259 characters for files, 248 for folders). See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247.aspx for full details.

My guess is that you've recently moved the file into a new subfolder. It could also be an invalid filename. It's hard to say without knowing what your ActiveWorkbook.Path is.

Here's my PDF Export Function:

```
Dim v As Variant
Dim Fname As String
Dim PdfFile As String

'Remove invalid characters from filenames
Fname = "test" 'Build your filename here
For Each v In Array("/", "\", "|", ":", "*", "?", "<", ">", """")
    Fname = Replace(Fname, v, "_")
Next

'Export activesheet as PDF
    PdfFile = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & Fname & ".pdf"
    With ActiveSheet
    .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=PdfFile, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
    End With
```

This'll output the PDF into the same location as your excel file.